# Extend Localization in .NET: No Resource found = translate "on the fly"

Tags: blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-localization

I am using Asp Net Localization with SQL in my Blazor .NET 6 App (Server).
I have content in my app that should not be in the SQL/Resource table and thus needs to be translated "on the fly".

At what point can I catch this?

-> If the entry is not found in the Resource/SQL table, the entry should be translated via my Google/Deepl API and returing the translated string.

Who knows about this and can tell me the right place or implementation?

thank you in advance

Comment: I didn't catch your point, you have all the keywords that you need, you have just to search.

Comment: [XLocalizer](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/index.md) already providing such functionality.